# Disable h:inputText with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf

I'm trying to make a h:inputText disable status dynamic, through jQuery (not using reRender because of the performance).

I have a javascript function, wich is responsible for updating the value and other statuses for a bunch of h:inputText. No problem updating their values, but when it comes to updating the disable status strange things happen. I cannot actually disable a field, even trying all the options below:

```
jQuery(document.getElementById('form:fieldID')).attr('disabled', 'disabled');  

jQuery(document.getElementById('form:fieldID')).attr('disabled', true);

jQuery(document.getElementById('form:fieldID')).prop('disabled', true);
```

Calling any of the options above on a field, will result in a final html equals to `<input disabled="">`, which will also enable the previously disabled fields.

I've tested this with JSF 1.2 and a bunch of versions of jQuery.

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('formID:fieldID')`. Example `<h:inputText id="answerForSQ" label="#{msg.answerForSQ}"
 value="#{securityQuestionsForm.answerForSQ}"
 styleClass="#{not securityQuestionsForm.secAnswerValid ? 'error' : ''}"
 onkeypress="if(window.event.keyCode==13){
 window.name='answerQuestionWindow';  document.getElementById('answerQuestionForm:answerQues').focus();}">
 </h:inputText>`

Comment: Oh, forgot to say: I've used the full qualified ids for the elements

Comment: try jQuery('#fieldID').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); Hope this helps

Comment: @SrikanthGanji this is equivalent to the first option in my example.

Comment: @Joao Mosquito I tested it  "jQuery('#fieldID').attr('disabled', 'disabled');"  in one of my pages and it is working like a charm. Why don't you try  jQuery('#form\\:fieldID').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); you have to escape the special characters with '\\'. If you want to enable it then jQuery('#form\\:fieldID').removeAttr('disabled'); Hope this helps

Comment: The selection of the elements through jQuery isn't the problem. They are selected just fine and their dom is allright when debbuging. The only problem is the way they're rendered in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

```
$("[name$=':fieldID']").attr("disabled", true); //for normal input field
$("[name$=':fieldID']").attr("disabled", true); //for checkbox and radiobutton (disable all options)
$("[name$=':fieldID'][id$=':1']").attr("disabled", true); //for checkbox and radiobutton second option
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I'm already able to select the elements I want with jQuery, and when debbuging in the browser, the DOM tree is the way I want it to be. But when the elements are displayed by the browser, all the elements that I tried to disable are with an empty 'disabled' property